# Group the datetime based on another array of the datetime in pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Assume I have two pandas dataframe with two columns of datetime as follow:

| Col_1 | Col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 9:00 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-02 20:00 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-03 1:00 |
| 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-04 9:00 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-05 16:00 |
|  | 2023-01-06 9:00 |
|  | 2023-01-08 12:00 |

And I want to fit Col_2 datetime base on Col_1 datetime with following condition:

If the datetime aheads 12pm, it stays with same date if the Col_1 has the same date, if not, it will switch the next Col_1 datetime. If the time pass or equal to 12pm, it will switch to the next date based on Col_1 datetime.

However, if the last value is pass 12pm and there is no relevant date from Col_1, just add one day base on the last day in Col_1

For example, I expect Col_2 will look like below:

| Col_1 | Col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-04 |
| 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-08 |
|  | 2023-01-08 |
|  | 2023-01-09 |

Is there any function to do so in pandas? Or how can I write the code?

Comment: are these two columns from two different dataframes?

Comment: Yes, they are from differen DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom function that looks up the date in `df1`, and then apply it to `df2['Col_2']`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_1': pd.to_datetime([
        '2023-01-02',
        '2023-01-03',
        '2023-01-04',
        '2023-01-05',
        '2023-01-08'
    ])
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_2': pd.to_datetime([
        '2023-01-02 9:00',
        '2023-01-02 20:00',
        '2023-01-03 1:00',
        '2023-01-04 9:00',
        '2023-01-05 16:00',
        '2023-01-06 9:00',
        '2023-01-08 12:00'])
})

## create a function that takes a datetime as an input, 
## and returns the correct datetime from df1 'Col_1' as a reference
def get_date_from_df1(ts, df1):
    ts_in_df1 = sum(df1['Col_1'] == ts.floor(freq='d'))
    ## get index of the the ts:
    if ts_in_df1 == 1:
        if ts.hour < 12:
            idx = df1.loc[df1['Col_1'] == ts.floor(freq='d')].index[0]
        elif (ts.hour == 12) & (ts.minute == 0):
            idx = df1.loc[df1['Col_1'] == ts.floor(freq='d')].index[0]
            if idx + 1 > df1.index[-1]:
                return ts.ceil(freq='d')
        else:
            idx = df1.loc[df1['Col_1'] == ts.floor(freq='d')].index[0] + 1

    elif sum(df1['Col_1'] > ts.floor(freq='d')) == 1:
        idx = df1.loc[df1['Col_1'] > ts.floor(freq='d')].index[0]
    
    ## if the date isn't found in df1, we return None (to avoid an error)
    else:
        return None

    return df1['Col_1'].iloc[idx]

df2['Col_2'] = df2['Col_2'].apply(lambda ts: get_date_from_df1(ts, df1))
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
       Col_2
0 2023-01-02
1 2023-01-03
2 2023-01-03
3 2023-01-04
4 2023-01-08
5 2023-01-08
6 2023-01-09
```